# Refresh many Google Map markers position, without refresh the whole map in Android

Tags: android, google-maps, position, refresh, markers

I'm currently developing an Android app that have to receive GPS positions from other devices every minutes, and display them on a map.
I'm using the GoogleMaps Api V2,

What i'd like to do, is to refresh the position marker very time a new position is received. (I don't want to refresh the whole map)

For the moment, I've added a button in the menu that enables me to refresh the entire map.

To detail to structure, I have a service that run MQTT, and every time a position is received, I add it into an Hashmap, that represents my map data source.
This HashMap is a Singleton that extends Observable.
Moreover, my fragment that display the my implements Observer.

*Code from my Fragment that implements Observer*

```
 public void update(Observable observable, final Object object)
 {

     if (observable instanceof ListPositions && object != null)
     {        
         Position p = (Position) object;
         LatLng position = new LatLng(p.getLatitude(), p.getLongitude());
         // Where i'd like to move the markers

     }
     else
     {
        // Where i'd like to remove the marker from the map
     }
 }
```

*Code From my Singleton List of position*

```
public class ListPositions extends Observable{

private HashMap<String,Position> mapPosition;

private ListPositions()
{
    mapPosition = new HashMap<String, Position>();
    VehicleMapFragment mapFragmentObserver = new VehicleMapFragment();
    this.addObserver(mapFragmentObserver);
}


private static ListPositions INSTANCE = null;


public static synchronized ListPositions getInstance()
{
    if (INSTANCE == null)
    { INSTANCE = new ListPositions();
    }
    return INSTANCE;
}

public int getNumberOfPosition()
{
    return mapPosition.size();
}

public void addPosition(String key, Position p){
    mapPosition.put(key,p);
    setChanged();
    notifyObservers(p);
}

public void removePosition(String key){
    mapPosition.remove(key);
    setChanged();
    notifyObservers();
}
```

*Code From myService that runs MQTT*

```
public void onPositionMessageReceived(MqttMessage message, String source)
 {
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String s = gson.toJson(message.toString());
    String jsonPosition = gson.toJson(message.toString());
    jsonPosition = formatMessage(jsonPosition);
    Position p = gson.fromJson(jsonPosition, Position.class);

    ListPositions.getInstance().addPosition(source, p);


}
```

Can someone know how to move each markers individually without refreshing the whole map, in my update function from my Observer Fragment?
May I use a Handler to update the Map, from an other thread to modify the Main UI Thread ?

Many thanks

EDIT :

Because the first methode given by AniV didn't work for me, I've tried with an Asyntask that runs when my Observer get a notification from the Observable List.

Code from the Observer Fragment :

```
public void update(Observable observable, final Object object)
{
    if (observable instanceof ListPositions && object != null)
    {
        Position p = (Position) object;

        position = new LatLng(p.getLatitude(), p.getLongitude());
        options = new MarkerOptions().position(position).title("TEST").snippet("TEST");

        PositionUpdate positionUpdaterTask = new PositionUpdate(myGoogleMap, options, position);
    positionUpdaterTask.execute();
    }
}
```

Code from the AsyncTask :

```
public class PositionUpdate extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{

private GoogleMap myGoogleMap;
private MarkerOptions options;
private LatLng positionToAdd;


public PositionUpdate(GoogleMap googleMap, MarkerOptions options, LatLng position)
{
    this.myGoogleMap = googleMap;
    this.options = options;
    this.positionToAdd = position;
}


@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void...voids)
{
    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid)
{
    if (myGoogleMap != null)
    {
        myGoogleMap.addMarker(options.position(positionToAdd));
        Log.i(ConstElisa.LOG_ELISA, "MARKER ADDED");
    }
    else
    {
        Log.e(ConstElisa.LOG_ELISA, "ERROR ADDING THE MARKER");
    }

    super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
}
```

However, in this case, myGoogleMap variable is always null, so the marker is never added to the Google Map.

Does someone have an idea why this variable is null ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally succeeded in doing that thing by using the AsyncTask.

In my EDIT, I said that I had some trouble with the null instance of my Google Maps object.
This was caused by my Singleton Observable. Indeed, in the constructor, I used

```
VehicleMapFragment mapFragmentObserver = new VehicleMapFragment();
this.addObserver(mapFragmentObserver);
```

This code sample recreated another instance of my Fragment, and that the reason why ii had Null objects.

To correct this problem, I simply used :

```
ListPositions.getInstance().addObserver(this);
```

in my Fragment Observer.

So if you want to update a marker position without refreshing the whole map, 
you can use the Observer/Observable Pattern, and use an Asynctask to update the marker position.

Comment: Great Job... Good for my reference too :)

Answer (score 0):

You have two options here:

- Either update the marker position programatically using setPosition() method.

  ```
  Marker marker = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(entry.getValue()).title(entry.getKey()));
  ```

  Use this object to change its position:

  ```
   marker.setPosition(new LatLng(5, 5));
  ```
- OR as you said, Make use of Handlers:

  ```
  Handler locationHandler;
  final static long REFRESH = 10 * 1000;
  final static int SUBJECT = 0;
  private GoogleMap mMap;
  private Marker myMarker = null;
  ```

  and onCreate()

  ```
  locationHandler = new Handler() {
  public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
      if (msg.what == SUBJECT) {
          updateMarker();
          this.sendEmptyMessageDelayed(SUBJECT, REFRESH);
      }
  }
  };
  ```

Handler option is better in cases where you have to update the position at a specific time interval.

Comment: Well... The first solution isn't working, because updating the marker by removing/adding run on the UI thread, and my app crash.
Can I have more explaination about the second one, and how the use of the handler could help me in this case? With your code sample, I don't really see how to integrate it to work with my update(Observable observable, final Object object) method.
Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have something like this. I receive a list of devices every 5 minutes to update locations of the map.

What do you think about this

```
private HashMap<String, Marker> mMarkers = new HashMap<>();    

private void drawDevicesOnMap() {
            if (isMapReady) {
                for (Device device : mDeviceList) {

                    List<com.model.Location> locationList = device.getLocations();

                    if (locationList != null && !locationList.isEmpty()) {
                        if (mMarkers.containsKey(device.getId())) {  //update
                            Marker m = mMarkers.get(device.getId());
                            m.setPosition(device.getLocations().get(0).getCoordinates().getLatLng());
                            mMarkers.put(device.getId(), m);
                        } else { //add
                            MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
                            markerOptions.position(locationList.get(0).getCoordinates().getLatLng());
                            markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(device.getHue()));
                            markerOptions.title(device.getNickname());
                            Marker marker = mMap.addMarker(markerOptions);
                            mMarkers.put(device.getId(), marker);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

if the marker for a device with x id is found in the HashMap, you update its location.